# Static IP without router access?

Tags: linux, ssh, server, ip, router

I am currently living at the student homes to my university. I want to set up a NAS / server to run backups, VM and some other small task. This is also something I want to set up to learn more about Linux and networking. I am currently planning how to set it up and what hardware to buy, but I want to run arch Linux on it with RAID 1. A problem I'm thinking about is that I don't have access to the router and therefore I can't set up port forwarding to connect to the server. Is there a way to get remote access to it without adjusting the settings in the router?

Comment: Use [tor](https://www.torproject.org/) network. http://unethicalblogger.com/2012/06/13/ssh-as-a-hidden-service.html

Comment: Interesting @IporSircer . Can it be used with Plex, ftp, ssh and all other features of a server? But it must be accessed through a .onion address right, and the data will be transferred through nodes? Wouldn't the speed performance be poor, considering OP will use this as a NAS and VM?

Comment: This technique opens a port, so you can use any vpn (openvpn is recommended) solution to reach your machine just like be in the same lan. And there are some vpn solutions over ssh: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VPN_over_SSH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my University we have the ability to connect to a vpn so we can access services only available through a specific University IP.

I haven't tested this method but I believe it could work.

Set up your services like normal and configure them to use port 80 if they need any data from the outside.
Make a script, probably available somewhere, to send you your internally ip address on e.g. mail. 
That way you can use your schools VPN service to connect to the lan and from there you can access an internal ip address(your server).

This all depends on this VPN service and if you are connected to the same network.

@iporSircor commented on a method you can use. It's basically the same as what I wrote, but instead of connecting to schools VPN you will connect to your own VPN(server).

Test it out and let us know what method you used, what worked, what didn't.

And also you should talk to your school to find out if using Tor or even setting up a server on their network is allowed.